# Binary reading returning zero

Tags: c, binary, binaryfiles, binary-data

I'm trying to read a binary file and display its contents in the terminal, but this line of code:

```
size_t readed = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), positionX, file);
```

It is returning zero, so my loop is stopped, what is the suggestion to solve this problem?

```
buffer = Storage
sizeof(buffer) = Size File
positionX = 7918080 <-- Dynamic Pointer
file = File to read
```

Terminal output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9pls.png

My complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: Please insert the file to read\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *file;

        file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

        //Cannot open file --> check pointer file after fopen
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot open file \n");
            exit(0);
        }

        long positionX = ftell(file);

        printf("Pointer at the beginning %ld\n", positionX);

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

        positionX = ftell(file);

        rewind (file); // Sets the position indicator associated with stream to the beginning of the file

        unsigned char buffer[positionX]; // o buffer deveria ser criado aqui depois de pegar a posição final

        printf("Pointer at the End: %ld\n", positionX);

        // Read the content --> it's always good to check the read value
        // the third parameter was 1, it should be "position"
        size_t readed = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), positionX, file);

        printf("the size is %zu\n", readed);  // decimal size_t ("u" for unsigned)
        printf("the size is %zx\n", readed);  // hex size_t

        for(size_t i = 0; i < readed; i++) // usar readed como limite
        {
            printf("%x ", buffer[i]); // prints a series of bytes
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to read `positionX*positionX` bytes.

Comment: I need to read the entire contents of the file and [ positionX ] is the position of the pointer within the file, when the [ positionX ] is on the last byte the loop stops.

Comment: Please check the documentation of `fread` and what each parameter means. `positionX` in your case is the size of the file *and* the size of the buffer

Comment: I added more details to the question. I've read this documentation and it looks like it's okay with my fread(). What is wrong ? https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `fread` is incorrect:

```
size_t readed = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), positionX, file);
```

The second parameter is the size of each element to read, and the third is the number of elements.  This means that you're attempting to read up to `sizeof(buffer) * positionX` bytes, but `buffer` isn't that big.  As a result, you write past the end of the buffer triggering undefined behavior.

Since you're reading `positionX` individual characters, you want 1 for the member size:

```
size_t readed = fread(buffer, 1, positionX, file);
```

Comment: The `buffer` is not written past its end, because the file is not big enough. `buffer` is a VLA with exactly the same size as the file. I would expect `fread()` to return 1, because this is the number of elements of size `sizeof buffer` that could be read. -- Anyway, to have automagically the correct numbers, the call `fread(buffer, sizeof buffer[0], sizeof buffer / sizeof buffer[0], file)` would be a better statement.